# Network error: Trying to get property of non-object in php

Tags: php

I am creating a simple php and js forget password.I have looked at other examples of this question but cannot find the answer. If someone could link an answer that is similar to mine, that would be great, alternatively, giving suggestions under this post would be great also. I have got the PHP code, which is below, it is saying that there are no errors in the php code, however when I go onto the network it is saying this:

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **URL** on line **10**

PHP

```
require_once('config1.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM zz_login WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {

    } else 
        exit (json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please check your inputs'))); 
}
```

Line 10 is **if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {**

Not sure what is wrong with it, if anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$sql` variable is a **string** (your sql query). That's why you get the notice - string is not an object and does not have a `num_rows` property.

You probably meant to write:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but it didn't work. Although now it got rid of the error, however why isn't the message appearing? I thought it was meant to

Answer (score 0):

`$sql` is a string, so `$sql->num_rows` is a bad mistake. You must do:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```